# Is there any way to change function prototypes at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

suppose you have to write code that should compile under C++,C++11,C++17,etc.

A function like this for example.

```
bool Ispalindrome(const std::string &str) 
{ 
   // Code 
}
```

That compiles under all C++ implementations. But if you want to use the old and the new the C++17 string_view feature you have deal with something similar to

```
#ifdef LEGACYCPP
   bool Ispalindrome(const std::string &str) 
  { 
     // Code 
  }
#elseif CPP17
  bool Ispalindrome(std::string_view str) 
  { 
     // OMG Repeated Code 
  }
#endif
```

Using conditional compiling is right, but have to repeat code.

Is there any way to choose a function prototype at compile time ? Or other way to circumvent double coding ? (in situations where it can be applied)

Thanks

Comment: Well, you can put only the first line (or only the parameter list) inside the `#ifdef/.../#endif` - so long as the different parameter types can be used interchangeably in the function body. It'll probably work for this.

Comment: How likely is it that your code will actually be compiled for non-C++17 compilers? An advantage of C++ compared to other platforms (like Java, .NET, etc) is that you're not limited by the platform on your users' systems, only your build machine's platform. Unless you're _contractually obligated_ to support versions of C++ and the STL prior to C++17 then put your foot-down and proudly say that you won't compromise your project for the sake of users who refuse to use modern compiler toolchains. And if it's an open-source project then if anyone asks for C++11 support, tell them to submit a PR.

Comment: Very likely to have old compilers if you code for a video game console.

Comment: You should show that `// Code` in order to get more than generic tips.

Comment: I feel like you are trying too much. Easier to just get a string_view implementation for c++11 and swing with that https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite . Also, what console would not support c++17, out of curiosity ?

Comment: @AndreiDamian ty for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can be *sure* that the code section of your function will be *equivalent* in each case, then you can use a macro definition for the parameter list:

```cpp
#ifdef ISCPP17
#define PALIN_PARAMS std::string_view str
#else
#define PALIN_PARAMS const std::string& str
#endif
bool Ispalindrome(PALIN_PARAMS) 
{ 
    // Code 
}
#undef PALIN_PARAMS
```

There are, of course, many variations on this theme: you could leave out the "str" part in the macro definition and have `(PALIN_PARAMS str)` in the signature. But, using "as is" will also allow for multiple parameters with different types.

But I'm not sure this sort of thing will pass the *Inquisitions* of the `C++` Puritans.

Another (possibly more robust) way would be to use conditional compilation blocks with `using` (or `typedef`) statements to define argument types:

```cpp
#ifdef ISCPP17
using cnststrg = std::string_view; // Or typedef std::string_view cnststrg;
#else
using cnststrg = const std::string&;
#endif
bool Ispalindrome(cnststrg str)
{
    // Code 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A small issue of this approach is that, if there are more such functions then every time we must `#undef PALIN_PARAMS` or use different macro names with them by tracking. Better to undef, as compiler warning of redefine can be missed sometimes.

Comment: @iammilind I 100% agree! The issue of when (or *if*) to use such a macro would depend very much on how often such an issue occurred, and how many possible variants there may be. But your point of using `#undef` is well made (see edit).

Comment: Use `#undef` before the `#ifdef` starts to be on the safer side. The 2nd approach may not work trivially for 2 or more arguments unless you `typedef` each of them.

Comment: @iammilind Indeed, the second approach will only work if the general *shape* of the argument list is similar (and will require typedef/using for each 'variant' arg. type). On where to use `#undef` - that's a matter of style, I guess.

Comment: When `#undef` is used in the beginning it's guaranteed that the stale definition is cleared. If you use it in bottom as your code, the reader is not sure if it's still defined before. The former approach offers better readability than the latter.

Answer (score 4):

In a header file, you'll need to do something like

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
   #include <string_view>
   bool Ispalindrome(std::string_view str);
#else
   #include <string>
   bool Ispalindrome(const std::string &str);
#endif
```

In your definition, you'll need to include the header and then do

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
    bool Ispalindrome(std::string_view str) 
#else
    bool Ispalindrome(const std::string &str)
#endif
{ 
 // OMG no repeated code 
}
```

`__cplusplus` is specified in the standard, and is predefined in every compilation unit.   `201703L` indicates a C++17 compiler, larger values more recent standards.

This assumes an implementation (compiler and library) that correctly claims compliance with the respective C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

Provided it's exactly repeated code then, do following minor change:

```
#ifdef CPP17
  bool Ispalindrome(std::string_view str)
#else // all versions of LEGACYCPP
  bool Ispalindrome(const std::string &str)
#endif
  { 
     // Same Code 
  }
```

If a minor part of function is unique to versions, then apply the above same trick there too.